# No bookmarks with revtex 4-1

Tags: bookmarks, revtex

I used the following sample codes to produce bookmarks in the compiled PDF files. It turned out that on the left side of the PDF file, the only bookmark is the title. However, if I change the `revtex4-1` to `revtex4`, I can see the three bookmarks for the three sections. Who can help me out? thanks!

```
\documentclass[article]{revtex4-1} 

\usepackage{amssymb,amsbsy,bm,amsmath,psfrag,dsfont}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{blabla}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}

dfaf

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{aaaa}

\section{bbbb}

\section{cccc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The title is at the top layer. You need to expand it (click on the + beside it) to reveal the rest of the hierarchy.

Comment: You could also use `\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}` in order to show bookmarks open at opening of document, down to level 2, i.e. `subsection`.

Answer (score 3):

The title sits at the top of the bookmark hierarchy, with everything nested below it:

[image]

If you wish to adjust this nesting, you could switch to the (preferred) [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) and execute a `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` to reset the nesting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
%\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{blabla}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
An abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\section{aaaa}
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}

\end{document}
```

Note how `bookmark` automatically places the `Abstract` (unnumbered section) in the bookmarks.

Comment: It's very helpful!